# Iterating through two ArrayLists parallell in struts2

Tags: java, jsp, arraylist, struts2, ognl

I have two Array lists

```
private ArrayList<String> userPics = new ArrayList<String>();
private ArrayList<String> picLikes = new ArrayList<String>();
```

The first arraylist contains the paths of the image and the other list contains the no.of likes each picture got. i need to get the value in parallel in struts2 using the iterator tag. How to do it..?

Comment: How they are linked with each other?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you are "linking" them with the index, you can use IteratorStatus like follows:

```xml
<s:iterator value="userPics" var="pics" status="ctr">
    Current Element from userPics: <s:property value="pics" />
    Current Element from picLikes: <s:property value="picLikes[%{#ctr.index}]" />
</s:iterator>
```

But it would be 10 times better to create an object with those two attributes, and a List of them:

```java
public class Picture {
    private byte[] picture;
    private int likes;
    /* getters and setters */
}
```

then in your Action:

```java
private List<Picture> pics;
/* getter and setter */
```

and finally in your JSP:

```xml
<s:iterator value="pics">
    Current Element from userPics: <s:property value="picture" />
    Current Element from picLikes: <s:property value="likes" />    
</s:iterator>
```